# How to set device password using managed profile in Android 5.0

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, device-admin

I am working on managed profile application in android 5.0 while trying to set password using code given below.

```
manager.resetPassword("123456",DevicePolicyManager.RESET_PASSWORD_REQUIRE_ENTRY);
```

But it's throwing an exception like *Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: You can not reset the password for a managed profile.* 
is there any work around to set the password using managed profile owner.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. java.lang.SecurityException is because managed profile owner cannot reset the primary user's password.
2. The managed profile owner can set the password quality but resetting the password is not allowed.

Comment: any workarounds, how can we unlock a device then? I was doing before manager.resetPassword("",DevicePolicyManager.RESET_PASSWORD_REQUIRE_ENTRY);